# Issues with macos GCC toolchain compiling simple hello world

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, macos-mojave

I am having some issues with my gcc configuration on macOS 10.14.6.

hello.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "Hello World.";
}
```

command:

```
$ gcc -o hello hello.cpp
```

Response:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
      std::__1::ctype<char> const& std::__1::use_facet<std::__1::ctype<char> >(std::__1::locale const&) in hello-1b0e0e.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const in hello-1b0e0e.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string(unsigned long, char) in hello-1b0e0e.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in hello-1b0e0e.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in hello-1b0e0e.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::~sentry()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in hello-1b0e0e.o
  "std::__1::cout", referenced from:
      _main in hello-1b0e0e.o
  "std::__1::ctype<char>::id", referenced from:
      std::__1::ctype<char> const& std::__1::use_facet<std::__1::ctype<char> >(std::__1::locale const&) in hello-1b0e0e.o
  "std::__1::locale::~locale()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const in hello-1b0e0e.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrow()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in hello-1b0e0e.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)", referenced from:
      std::__1::ios_base::setstate(unsigned int) in hello-1b0e0e.o
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in hello-1b0e0e.o
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in hello-1b0e0e.o
      ___clang_call_terminate in hello-1b0e0e.o
  "___cxa_call_unexpected", referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::ostreambuf_iterator(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in hello-1b0e0e.o
  "___cxa_end_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in hello-1b0e0e.o
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in hello-1b0e0e.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in hello-1b0e0e.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::ostreambuf_iterator(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in hello-1b0e0e.o
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const in hello-1b0e0e.o
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in hello-1b0e0e.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have already read these:

[Can't compile a C program on a Mac after upgrading to Catalina 10.15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278260/cant-compile-a-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrading-to-catalina-10-15)

[GCC Missing Headers on macOS10.15 with Xcode11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58144137/gcc-missing-headers-on-macos10-15-with-xcode11)

[Compiling with gcc in macOS Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52974321/compiling-with-gcc-in-macos-mojave)

And I have already installed this:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandlineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

Comment: Are you using Homebrew gcc, or just the clang alias that comes with Xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
$ gcc -o hello hello.cpp
```

to:

```
$ g++ -o hello hello.cpp
```

(otherwise with gcc you don’t automatically get required C++ libraries linked and would have to specify them explicitly).

Comment: okay-- that worked. But why doesn't gcc or clang work?

Comment: Ugh-- thanks for the tip! All of those other posts, no one mentioned it.

Comment: I just added an explanation - you can use gcc but then you would need to use something like `gcc -lstdc++`.